# Installing Backtrack/Pentesting OS on AWS/AZURE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I tried good search but i am unable to get any help on this topic.

Is there any official/unofficial way to install these OS on these cloud hosting. I don't know if it against there tos or not.

Disclaimer : I am going to Pentest my own Web Properties.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's BackTrack, not "black".

Second, they're allowed. Get the ISO from the official website, upload, mount, boot. For AWS you'll have to grab the VMware image and import that.

Third, using them to test anything you don't own is 1. Against the TOS 2. Illegal in most places (certainly in the US; probably in Sweden too)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i also want to know if BackTrack can be installed on Azure or not?

Comment: Yep. Same process. You could also use either Hyper-V or Virtual Server to create a VHD with the install and upload that.

Comment: Is there any detailed guide that i can refer to?

Comment: Honestly, if you need a detailed guide to getting a VM running in AWS or Azure, you almost certainly should not be running BackTrack. It's the thermo-nuclear weapon of security tools. I'd highly recommend getting a book about it and following that. [BackTrack4: Assuring Security by Penetration Testing](http://www.amazon.com/BackTrack-Assuring-Security-Penetration-Testing/dp/1849513945) is slightly dated, but has plenty of good relevant material.

Comment: Unless I've missed something major, it's not possible to boot an EC2 instance off of an iso.

Comment: @EEAA Eep, you're right. I blame it on posting answers at 1AM. Same is true of Azure. There are cloud providers who will let you boot a VM from an ISO too.

Comment: NP. I do wish that were possible, though. It would make my life much easier as I deal with our EC2 clusters.